# Tangent of a parameterized curve and the derivative of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, tangent-line, parametrization

A parametrized curve is a function $\gamma : (\alpha,\beta)\to \mathbb R^n$.
The parametrized curve for a straight line with slope $m$ passing through origin is $\gamma(\alpha,\beta)={\{(t,mt)}\}$ where $t\in(\alpha,\beta)$
$\dot\gamma(t)=(1,m)$
$||\dot\gamma||=\sqrt{1+m^2}$
If we see the equation $y=mx$ the image of the set of points follow this equation also represent the straight line curve.
Also, $\frac{dy}{dx}=m$

Basically, $||\dot\gamma||=\sqrt{1+m^2}$ is the magnitude of speed with which the point travels.
I have two questions-

1. The question is that what does $\frac{dy}{dx}=m$ represents? As it also represents the rate at which y changes with x. Then how it is different from $||\dot\gamma||=\sqrt{1+m^2}$.
   Basically what is the difference between $m$ and $||\dot\gamma||$? Why there values are different?
2. I want to know what is the difference between $y=mx$ and $\gamma(t)$ if $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$?

I have studied about only real analysis and basic mathematics till. So please explain accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a consequence of Pythagoras. Draw a triangle of base $1$ and height $m$ equal to the slope. $\sqrt{1+m^2}$ is the hypothenuses.
2. There is no difference (but $\gamma$ is parameterized).

Comment: Yes, I understand that how $||\dot\gamma||=\sqrt{1+m^2}$ due to pythagoras theorem. My question is that why $dy/dx$ which equals $m$ comes out to be different from $||\dot\gamma||=\sqrt{1+m^2}$ as both represent the rate of change of curve?

Comment: @Iti: "both represent the rate of change of curve": what ?? Try to give a rigorous meaning to this statement.

Comment: In first case, in parameterized curve, $||\dot\gamma(t_0)||$ is the limit $t\to 0$, $||\frac{\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_0)}{t}||$ and in second case , $y=mx$, $dy/dx$ at $x_0$ is limit $t\to 0$, $\frac{y(x)-y(x_0)}{x}$.

Comment: So basically the confusion is that what is the difference between $||\dot\gamma(t)||$ and $dy/dx$ as they are giving different values and intuitively I think to be same. Please clarify my doubt. Where I am incorrect?

Comment: @Iti: don't look at the differential definitions, they tell you nothing. Find the geometric interpretations of these "rates".

Comment: May you explain a little bit more. Like I am not able to make a conclusion regarding the difference between $||\dot\gamma(t)||$ and $dy/dx$. Please don't mind if it is a trivial question. But I am not able to make conclusion.